# execution of aclocal fails

Tags: linux, ubuntu, autotools, autoconf, building

upon executing `autoreconf -i` the following error returns

```
/usr/local/bin/aclocal: 14: /usr/local/bin/aclocal: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 2
```

and execution of aclocal fails  e.g `aclocal --version` returns error:

```
/usr/local/bin/aclocal: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `[AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS],'
/usr/local/bin/aclocal: line 14: `m4_ifndef([AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS], [m4_defun([_AM_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS], [])m4_defun([AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS], [_AM_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS($@)])])'
```

on machine `4.10.0-38-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

removing automake, autoconf, and re-installing doesn't solve the problem, and i have no time to debug, any idea?

Comment: Adding some context such as relevants parts of the `configure.ac` might gives some hints. It seems to be a `aclocal.m4` error which is generated from the `configure.ac`

Answer (score 0):

removal of `/usr/local/bin/aclocal` on linux/GNU ubuntu and re-installation solved the problem, but the reason is unknown to me.